# How to avoid nilClass errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

If I try to check for values in my database, I sometimes get errors related to the fact that there were no hits from my query.

So I started using `.present?` to check if the query returned any result, before doing the original check.

Is there a smoother way to avoid nilClass errors than this?

```
temp = Event.where(basket_id: basket.basket_id).where(event_type: ["operatorJoined", "operatorDisconnected"]).last
if temp.present? && temp.event_type == "operatorJoined"
```

Comment: What's the relation between events and baskets? Why does basket has a basket_id field, that's not very Rails-y. You are doing `.last` you expect this query to return one or none right? `temp` is not a very good name, maybe `event`? `event.present?` is smooth enough, specially if you do it only once; it will depend on how often do you ask this for us to  give a better solution.

Comment: This was meant as an example code. The question is if I can avoid asking for .present? at all - and do this smoother in a one-liner.

Comment: The way the example code is written no, because `.last` will return one event or nil. You could always do `event.try(:event_type)`, but is that smoother? Hard to tell without more context.

Comment: If it returns nil (because of .last), I'd prefer the condition to be false, instead of the application failing due to a nilClass error.

I'll try to explain better. Let's say you have a table of users. I want to check if the last user is named Robin or not.

``if User.last.name == "Robin"``

This will work just fine, but it'll fail if the User-table is empty. How would you check this?

Comment: I understand your question just fine. And again, if you decide to go with `.last` be prepared to handle `nil` and `.present?` is a good way of doing it. I prefer it over the simpler `if temp &&` just because it's more explicit. If you are doing this again and again, then that's a smell that you might want to fix in a different way, but hard to tell with hypotheticals.

Comment: You can simply do: `if temp.try(:event_type) == 'operatorJoined'` (ex: `nil.try(:something) == 'some string'` returns `false`)

Answer (score 0):

You could be writing:

```
if temp && temp.event_type == "operatorJoined"
```

... or you might like to look at the Sandy Metz presentation "Nothing is Something" to learn more about avoiding this problem by using the Null Object pattern.

I would really hope this code would be something like:

```
temp = Basket.events.operator_join_or_disc.last
if temp && temp.operator_joined?
```

Comment: Since OP is using Rails, he can simply do: `if temp.try(:event_type) == 'operatorJoined'` (ex:  `nil.try(:something) == 'some string'` returns `false`)

Comment: Yes: I'm not a fan of `#try` though.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 2.3 introduced a safe call operator (I've seen it called safe navigation operator quite a lot, as well) `&.` which is similar to the [`try!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try-21) method in rails:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :the_other_a

  def do_something
    puts "doing something on #{object_id}"
  end
end

a = A.new

a.do_something # => shows 'doing something on 70306921519040'
a.the_other_a.do_something # => NoMethodError: undefined method `do_something' for nil:NilClass
a.the_other_a&.do_something # => nil

a.the_other_a = A.new
a.the_other_a&.do_something # => shows 'doing something on 70306910376860'

a.the_other_a&.do_something_else # => NoMethodError: undefined method `do_something_else' for #<A:0x007fe334d62738>

a.the_other_a.try(:do_something_else) # => nil
a.the_other_a.try!(:do_something_else) # => NoMethodError: undefined method `do_something_else' for #<A:0x007fe334d62738>
```

So, in your example something like this should work:

```
temp = Event.where(basket_id: basket.basket_id).where(event_type: ["operatorJoined", "operatorDisconnected"]).last
if temp&.event_type == "operatorJoined"
```

However, [`present?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F) just checks for `!blank?`, so if the variable (`temp` in this example) could be `false`, `''`, `' '`, `[]`, or `{}` (among any other things that would return `true` for `blank?`) then `temp.present? && temp.something_else` would not be the same as `temp&.something_else`. Doesn't apply in this situation, since it's the result of the ActiveRecord query, but something to keep in mind.